# working and filtering with large external lists using BCS

Tags: bcs, external-list

I have a large set of orders (about 7500) that I want to show in my SharePoint site. I'm using BCS because I also want to link the orders to documents.

I also have an external list with these orders, so that users can see the order data. The problem that I'm facing is that the external list itself loads too slow and if I want to filter in the list, the whole browser isn't responsive anymore. It loads all the 7500 records into memory.

Is there with BCS a way to load only 30 records, but still be able to filter on all records in the list? Or do I have to build my own webpart for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own webpart to do this :-(

Answer (score 0):

BCS only returns about 2000 records per call maximum, if I'm not mistaken. It is also recomanded of course to have at least a Limit filter as well as include other filter into the "Read List" methods. Have a look at this step-by-step by Scott Hillier which highlights a simillar scenario:

http://www.shillier.com/archive/2010/08/05/Using-Business-Connectivity-Services-to-Display-SharePoint-2010-ULS-Logs.aspx

Comment: I've created my own .net assembly connector and with sql server profiler I see everything getting retrieved. The problem with the limit filter is that in the external list, I only can filter on the retrieved records. Is there a way to show filters that are executed on the database instead of in memory?

Comment: I would go SQL Profiler as the tool to monitor/trace calls